# select optionlist jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="RB_0_field_select_0">
    <option value="">Select a Field</option> 
    <option value="Audit">Audit</option>
    <option value="Author">Author</option> 
    <option value="Barcode">Barcode</option>
    <option value="Category">Category</option>
    <option value="DocType">Content Type</option>
</select>

<script type="javascript">
    $('select[id="RB_0_field_select_0"]').change(function(){
        alert("hello");
        alert($(this).val());
        alert($( "#RB_0_field_select_0 option:selected" ).text());
    });
</script>
```

I want to print the value selected in option list but its not working.
   How to do this?

Comment: Even it is not printing hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, you just need to include jquery on top:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Here is a demo, I did not change anything in your code, i just added jquery**

```js
$('select[id="RB_0_field_select_0"]').change(function() {
  alert("hello");
  alert($(this).val());
  alert($("#RB_0_field_select_0 option:selected").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="RB_0_field_select_0">
  <option value="">Select a Field</option>
  <option value="Audit">Audit</option>
  <option value="Author">Author</option>
  <option value="Barcode">Barcode</option>
  <option value="Category">Category</option>
  <option value="DocType">Content Type</option>
</select>
```

**OR**
*Maybe your script runs before the document is loaded, if that is the case, do this:*

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('select[id="RB_0_field_select_0"]').change(function() {
       alert($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't alert even "hello" it means that you are binding event before DOM is loaded - so you don't attach event handler at all to anything. Try to do it on DOMContentLoaded event:

```
$(function() {
    $("#RB_0_field_select_0").change(function () {
        $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
```

or

```
$(this).options[$(this).selectedIndex].value;
```